# Como puedo poner en un input el valor que selecciono al darle click a la grafica que genero con chartjs?

Tags: php, chart.js

Estoy realizando una interfaz web donde muestro los datos graficados de una base de datos en un gráfico charjs.
Pero lo que quiero hacer es que al darle click en un punto de mi grafica pueda tomar esos valores y después pintarlos en algún otro lado por ejemplo abajo de mi tabla de datos o en un input. muestro el script en el cual ejecuto la petición mediante ajax para obtener los valores de mi base de datos.

**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        
        url: "apirest/DBAni_lectura.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            var ani_inst = [];
            var ani_med = [];
            var hora = [];
            var energia = [];
            var evento = [];
            var color = ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'];
            var bordercolor = ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'];
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data) {
                ani_inst.push({x:i, y:data[i].ani_inst});
                ani_med.push({x:i, y:data[i].ani_med});
                hora.push(data[i].hora);
                energia.push({x:i, y:data[i].energia});
                evento.push({x:i, y:data[i].evento});
            }
            const totalDuration = 10000;
 const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / ani_inst.length;
 const previousY = (ctx) => ctx.index === 0 ? ctx.chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(100) : ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(ctx.datasetIndex).data[ctx.index - 1].getProps(['y'], true).y;
 const animation = {
     x: {
        
         type: 'number',
         easing: 'linear',
         duration: delayBetweenPoints,
         from: NaN, // the point is initially skipped
         delay(ctx) {
             if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.xStarted) {
                 return 0;
             }
             ctx.xStarted = true;
             return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
         }
     },
     y: {
         type: 'number',
         easing: 'linear',
         duration: delayBetweenPoints,
         from: previousY,
         delay(ctx) {
             if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.yStarted) {
                 return 0;
             }
             ctx.yStarted = true;
             return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
         }
     }
 };
 const config = {
    label: 'hora',
     type: 'line',
     data: {
         datasets: [{
             label: 'ANI INST.',
             borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
             backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
             borderWidth: 1,
             radius: 0,
             tension: .7,
             data: ani_inst,
         },
         {
             label: 'ANI MEDIO',
             borderColor: 'rgb(255, 128, 0)',
             backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 128, 0)',
             borderWidth: 1,
             radius: 0,
             tension: .7,
             data: ani_med,
         },
         {
             label: 'evento',
             borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
             backgroundColor:'rgb(255,255,255)',
             borderWidth: 1,
             radius: 0,
             tension: .7,
             data: evento,
         }]
     },
     options: {
         animation,
         interaction: {
             intersect: false
         },
         scales: {
             x: {
                 type: 'linear'
             }
         },
         responsive:true,
     }
 };
 const configE = {
    label: 'hora',
     type: 'line',
     data: {
         datasets: [{
             label: 'ENERGÍA',
             borderColor: 'rgb(48,255,36)',
             backgroundColor:'rgb(48,255,36)',
             borderWidth: 1,
             radius: 0,
             tension: .7,
             data: energia,
         }]
     },
     options: {
         animation,
         interaction: {
             intersect: false
         },
         scales: {
             x: {
                 type: 'linear'
             }
         },
         responsive:true,
     }
 };
 
 const graph = document.querySelector("#graph");
 new Chart(graph, config);
 const graph2 = document.querySelector("#energia");
 new Chart(graph2, configE);
          
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**
las gráficas que genero de la base de datos quedan así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían orientarme de como lo puedo solucionar, por favor.